# GCC inline assembly targeting AMD6/x86_64

Tags: gcc, x86, sse2

So I'm trying to write some inline assembly that would load variables into SSE2 registers.
However the inline assembly isn't going that well.

I'm hitting a detour while compiling in GCC.

```
g++-4.8.2 -g -maes -msse4 aesni.c -o aesni
aesni.c:101:junk `ptr[%rax]' after expression
aesni.c:101:32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64
aesni.c:101:cannot do signed 4 byte relocation
aesni.c:102:junk `ptr[%rdx]' after expression
aesni.c:102:32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64
aesni.c:102:cannot do signed 4 byte relocation
```

Code:

```
#include <string.h> // string
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    // Nr = 10 (128bit), 12 (192bit), 14 (256bit)

    __attribute__((aligned (16))) unsigned char Key128bit[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c,  0x00 };

    __attribute__((aligned (16))) unsigned char Key192bit[] = { 0x8e, 0x73, 0xb0, 0xf7, 0xda, 0x0e, 0x64, 0x52, 0xc8, 0x10, 0xf3, 0x2b, 0x80, 0x90, 0x79, 0xe5,
                                                                0x62, 0xf8, 0xea, 0xd2, 0x52, 0x2c, 0x6b, 0x7b,  0x00 };

    __attribute__((aligned (16))) unsigned char Key256bit[] = { 0x60, 0x3d, 0xeb, 0x10, 0x15, 0xca, 0x71, 0xbe, 0x2b, 0x73, 0xae, 0xf0, 0x85, 0x7d, 0x77, 0x81,
                                                                0x1f, 0x35, 0x2c, 0x07, 0x3b, 0x61, 0x08, 0xd7, 0x2d, 0x98, 0x10, 0xa3, 0x09, 0x14, 0xdf, 0xf4,  0x00 };


    char Nr = 10; // 128bit / 12 for 192bit / 14 for 256bit


    /* zero out XMM registers */
    asm volatile ("PXOR %xmm0, %xmm0\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm1, %xmm1\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm2, %xmm2\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm3, %xmm3\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm4, %xmm4\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm5, %xmm5\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm6, %xmm6\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm7, %xmm7\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm8, %xmm8\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm9, %xmm9\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm10, %xmm10\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm11, %xmm11\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm12, %xmm12\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm13, %xmm13\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm14, %xmm14\n"
                  "PXOR %xmm15, %xmm15\n");


    __attribute__((aligned (16))) unsigned char *KeyRound0, *KeyRound1;
    __attribute__((aligned (16))) unsigned char KeyRound1Temp[16];


    switch(Nr+1)
    {
        case 11:
        KeyRound0 = Key128bit;
        break;
        case 13:
        KeyRound0 = Key192bit;

        memset( KeyRound1Temp, 0x00, 16);
        memcpy( KeyRound1Temp, Key192bit+16, 8);
        KeyRound1 = KeyRound1Temp;
        break;
        case 15:
        KeyRound0 = Key256bit;

        memcpy( KeyRound1Temp, Key256bit+16, 16);
        KeyRound1 = KeyRound1Temp;
        break;
    }


    asm volatile("MOVDQA qword ptr [%0], %%xmm0\n"
                 "MOVDQA qword ptr [%1], %%xmm0\n"
                : /* output operands */
                : /* input operands */ "r" (KeyRound0), "r" (KeyRound1)
                : /* list of clobbered registers */
                );

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `Intel` syntax but GCC expects `AT&T`

Comment: Why not just use intrinsics instead of raw asm ? You're just making more work for yourself for no real benefit otherwise.

Comment: @PaulR I know! But digging into assembly will help me dig into my code and understand it.

Comment: @Nazar554 Your saying that because I'm referring to qword ptr in my code. But that's not the case, cause AT&T assembly uses %% for register and the instructions have a suffix that refer to the operation size. But I've tried several options and I can't get to the inline to work.

Comment: @PaulR one of the symptoms when I was using the intrinsics the GCC compiler was scheduling memory loading and unloading by itself (I know that's it's job) and storing all the results in the same XMM register. Thus, giving me a hard time to look at the values in the register.

Comment: @PaulR besides if you don't dive into unknown territory you'll never learn anything! need to get out of the comfort zone.

Comment: Sure - it depends whether you're learning/experimenting or you have an actual job that you need to get done. Horses for courses, as they say...

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-masm=intel`?